# Single supply op amp with input attenuator

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I'm designing a guitar headphone amplifier that uses a single supply op-amp as the output stage to the headphones. I'm using a potentiometer after the final JFET stage and before the op-amps as a volume control (so that I can keep the overdrive tone from the final JFET stage).

[image: Schematic]

The part I'm unsure about is the C9/RV3/C14 part of the schematic. I've used C9 to block DC (from the JFET bias) to avoid potentiometer crackle, and C14 blocks DC to the inputs of the op-amps.

My question is, can I connect pin 1 of the potentiometer to V_gnd (currently connected to DC GND) and omit C14? If that's the case, does R14 stay connected, or does RV3's V_Gnd connection suffice as a reference for the op-amps? If RV3's connection alone is relied on, I'm worried that the changing resistance between the op-amp and V_gnd voltage divider will cause instability, but having both C9 and C14 seems superfluous.

Also, is DC GND the best point to connect C15 and C16, or would connecting them to V_gnd be beneficial?

Thanks!

Comment: Your circuits now look correct, you do not need to change anything. Without C14 RV3 at "low setting" will affect the op-amp DC voltage (RV3 will load V_gnd). And Yes C5 and C16 should be connected to the DC GND.

Comment: And why C10 ony 1µF?

Comment: @G36 Thanks! That's a relief.

C10 must be a typo - all the other big values are 10u.

Comment: @G36 I don't think RV3 will load V_gnd at "low setting" because there is no DC current through RV3, except the input bias current of U1A and U1B.

Comment: @DavidG25 But without C14 capacitor (short circuit) the RV3 will have an influence on the DC voltage at the opamp input.

Comment: @G36 I don't think RV3 will influence the DC voltage at the opamp input, if we ignore input bias current. Pin 3 and pin 2 of RV3 are at high impedance nodes at DC (capacitor and opamp input respectively). The only moderate impedance node at DC is pin 1 of RV3 and that is at V_gnd, so the op amp input voltage is just V_gnd.

Comment: @DavidG25 But what about the path between pin 2 and 1(GND) when the pot is at "low setting"?

Comment: @G36 you can image that V_gnd is a voltage source and the resistance between pin 1 and pin 2 is the source impedance. The load is the op amp inputs in parallel with C9. Because the load is very high impedance (at DC), it doesn't matter what the source impedance is, the load voltage will be the same. In other words, it doesn't matter what the poteniotmeter setting is.

Comment: @DavidG25 I was talking about this path https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kko2v.png

Comment: @G36 pin 1 is connected to V_gnd.

Comment: @DavidG25 Hmm, so we must be looking at two different schematics. Pin 1 on the OP schematic is clearly connected to DC GND (as well as a lower side of R2), not to the virtual ground V_gnd.

Comment: @G36 OP’s question is if he can remove C14 and connect pin 1 to V_gnd.

Comment: @DavidG25 You are right. I'm an idiot and I need to study reading comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

> can I connect pin 1 of the potentiometer to V_gnd (currently connected to DC GND) and omit C14?

Yes. The DC level of the non-inverting input will be at mid-supply (V_gnd), and that should be within the common mode input range of U1A and U1B. The volume control should be unchanged, because V_gnd is effectively an AC ground due to the large decoupling capacitors C10 and C11.

> If that's the case, does R14 stay connected, or does RV3's V_Gnd connection suffice as a reference for the op-amps?

R14 should be removed, as it will affect your volume control. It would be in parallel with pins 1 and 2 of the potentiometer.

> If RV3's connection alone is relied on, I'm worried that the changing resistance between the op-amp and V_gnd voltage divider will cause instability

Pin 3 of the potentiometer is not connected to any DC voltage, so the common mode voltage of U1A and U1B will be V_gnd no matter what the potentiometer setting will be. The one thing to watch out for is the input bias current of U1A and U1B. The common mode voltage *will* change with the potentiometer setting if the input bias current is large. I wouldn't imagine the input bias current would be so large that it would move the common mode voltage outside of the common mode input range.

The resistance to ground at the non-inverting input also has no effect on the amplifier's stability because there is no feedback to the non-inverting input.

> Also, is DC GND the best point to connect C15 and C16, or would connecting them to V_gnd be beneficial?

I don't think it matters if C15/16 are connected to DC GND or V_gnd, since both of those nodes are effectively AC ground. If there is a difference connecting them to DC GND or V_gnd, just increase the decoupling capacitance (C10/11).

Lastly, if U1A and U1B have a lot of current noise, different volume settings will have different amounts of noise since the source impedance to U1A and U1B will be changing. Consider picking op amps with low current noise.

Comment: Thanks! I've received PCBs and built one and it works well with low impedance sources (I don't have a guitar to test it with), but if I can reduce the component count that's always good.

There's also a little bit of hiss, but I think that's coming from the high impedance input, because it's present across all stages.

Comment: @JoeofLoath nice. Why do you need 2 pots “gain” and “volume”?

Comment: gain controls overdrive into the final JFET stage, and volume controls listening volume through the op amp. By balancing them you can get both the overdrive tone and listening volume you require.

Comment: Simply removing R14 isn't a good idea, the non-inverting inputs wouldn't have a DC path to "ground" (in this case R14 should be returned to a bias voltage at half the positive supply.) Op-amp inputs always need a DC path to a well-defined voltage, ground, or the output terminal they can't just be left floating.

Comment: @Bitrex OP isn’t asking to remove only R14, but to remove R14 and C14. The op amps have a DC path to ground through the pot RV3.

Comment: @DavidG25 thank you kindly for your correction I somehow missed that very important detail in the original post. If you slightly edit your answer such that my vote is no longer locked I will be happy to change my vote on your reply.

Comment: In the case of C15 and C16 I think it might be best to return those capacitors to V_gnd, with a possibly increased C10, rather than the circuit ground. with the rails split like this the ground is effectively a power supply bus, and any noise or hum on it can be injected directly into the op amp input terminal thru the large value unity-gain-at-DC capacitors. The "virtual ground" is well-filtered from noise on both supplies

Comment: @Bitrex you may be right, since the speaker current returns on GND rather than V_gnd, but I don’t think it matters if he has a ground plane.